# iOS Use regular expression to remove/replace substring in HTML string

Tags: html, ios, regex, fonts

I would like to use regular expression to find given font-family and replace that font-family with mine font; in my string and remove that from so the return value is the original string without new font family applied on it.

Ex.

```
<span style="font-family: TimesNewRoman; font-size: 12"><p>My text<br /><br />
<span style="font-family: 'Georgia','serif'; color: #1a1a1a;">Description is here</span> Detail description</strong></p>
</span>
```

Here I want to edit ‘Georgia’ with TimesNewRoman 
Note: ‘`Georgia`’ will be `dynamic`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=family\:\s)[\s\S]*?(?=[;\s])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qv7Zrw/1